# Home brew and beer pump

Tags: brewing, beginner

I made my own home brew last year and I am doing it again this year. However I want to know if its possible to set my home brew up to a pub beer pump. What I mean by a beer pump is the kind of thing you get in a pub that pulls you a pint (tap, jockey, or any other way with or without CO2, but not a complete kegerator).

Info on this would be great as I don't have a clue if it's possible or what I would need to buy.

Cheers Stu

Comment: whats a pub beer pump? I'm not sure I understood your question... Do you wanna brew your beer using a pump to recirculate the wort? If  so, are you asking for what parts you need buy etc ... ? Would you mind elaborating ?

Comment: Are you talking about having a keg and a tap? If so, take a look at this: http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showthread.php?t=162225

Comment: rondonctba - what i mean by a beer pump is the kind of thing you get in a pub that pulls you a pint.

Comment: Philippe - looks good but thats a bit too advanced for what i wanted.

Comment: Ohh. Ok. If you're looking for something simpler than that suggested by @Philippe, then a beer jockey box might attend your needs/budget. Check [this](https://www.kegworks.com/draft-beer/jockey-boxes) out. Take a look at the parts list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look for "Beer Engine hand pump". It requires no CO2 or pressurised kegs, the beer is held in a traditional cask and the appropriate lines connect the cask to the the hand pump. 4 or 5 pulls on the pump will draw your pint.

You can store the beer in other containers such as the more traditional home brew barrels, but you might find it harder to connect the tap to the lines.

Comment: so something like this the??
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Beer-Pump-Beer-Engine-EWL/311905584159?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIM.MBE%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D43781%26meid%3D9e48b7fdc11046dd8947ca33c291b221%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D6%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D132238823412

what lines would i need then for this to work. and this way would it be possible to just leave the homebrew in the Fermenting Bucket rather than putting it into a barrell ??

Comment: A beer pump connected to a brew barrel is not impossible but is not exactly advisable without "special precautions". The fermenting bucket would presumably contain the yeast/trub/stuff collected on the bottom of the bin, so some provision for avoiding pumping that would be a good idea. The next thing is time taken to empty the bucket. Too long and you may find the brew spoiling because withdrawing beer will import air and some microbes (in the absence of any CO2 injection or filter).  Lastly the pump works by vacuum, so it tends to de-gas the brew during dispensing -but good for low fizz beers

Comment: I would cyphen th even beer out of one bucket into another so the sediment is reduced. If I boughy that from ebay will that work with just a tube going straight into the bucket it's mainly for parties so cans fil the bucket when needed

Comment: You need to condition the beer normally, and in this case that would be in a barrel/keg/cask. If you then decanted into a FV/bucket just to connect to the hand pump, that might work for a one off party, but as Pete says, it won't keep.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** you can.

Equipment needed is.

Corney keg

CO2 tank

CO2 regulator

Beer faucet / Tap

Gas and beer lines & fittings

Something to mount the faucet to. Many will put on the front of a fridge that holds the keg.

Comment: Do I have to have a co2 bottle.

Answer (score 0):

This all sounds very British to me, so my yes will say: you can ferment your beer in a cask for the true pub experience. Wooden, plastic and (I think) stainless casks are available at home brew shops for this purpose.

However, using a hand pump at home might be considered excessive, since the pump is intended to draw beer from a cask in cellar up to the pub.

The basic method is to put the cask behind the bar and let gravity (and a bit of pressure) bring the beer out of the cask. OTOH, when you use a pump you can use a sparkler to aerate your beer while pouring (pumping), if that's something you want.

Comment: i want something along the lines of this 
https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/bf/58/1b/bf581bf8feb46a77d550b8b6d333e9ba--man-cave-shed-man-shed.jpg
With the two connected to my homebrew under the counter

Comment: At first sight I would say those are beer taps not hand pumps. Taps are gas pressured (less effort) and hand pumps are vacuum drawn (more effort). As a "home-pub style" it looks great!